# Jenkins Email Extension plugin and OAuth 2.0 Query

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-email-ext

I am using the Email Extension plugin in my Jenkins and sending e-mail notifications.

I am using my SMTP server with TLS enabled and need to authenticate the SMTP server via username and password to leverage services.

[SMTP configuration details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8er7B.png)

Today I received a note from my Outlook admin team saying that the primary authentication in Exchange Online is being disabled (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online) and I need to switch to the modern authentication mention (OAuth 2.0 token-based authorization).

Does this e-mail extension plugin support modern authentication mention (OAuth 2.0 token-based authorization?

Answer (score 1):

This question was captured in issue [JENKINS-69414](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-69414). It has been fixed in the 2.92 release of the email-ext plugin for Jenkins.

There is now a checkbox to use OAuth 2.0. Note that you should provide your OAuth 2.0 token as the password of the credentials that are set up under Extended E-mail Notification -> Advanced.

However I have not been able to get this to work with office365.com authentication. The plugin does not generate the OAuth2 access tokens, so you have to manually do that. However the tokens generated by office365 are only valid for 1 hour, so you'd have to update your email configuration every hour manually...